# onTextChanged freezes after the first run

Tags: android

I have two EditText on layout and I want simply add symbol to second edittext when first is changed

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.

    etInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput);
    etOutput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOutput);

    etInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            etOutput.append(charSequence);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

But it freezes after first run. For example, I enter "h" letter. It is added to the second edittext. But when I trying to enter some other symbols, there are not any reaction.

My error's logcat is here: http://pastebin.com/p2qizUU0

Comment: The code you posted seems proper, the issue in other part

Comment: Please add the exception part of the logcat in the question. Also, the linked logcat says there's a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` in `symbolToCode` which you haven't included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Dont add to the EditText directly. Use editable instead.

```
etInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        etOutput.append(charSequence);
        Editable edtOutput = etOutput.getText();
        edtOutput.clear();
        edtOutput.insert(0,charSequence);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In onTextChanged you can do it this way:

```
String str = etOutput.getText().toString();
str+=charSequence.toString();
etOutput.settext(str);
```

directly appending to edittext i believe is the problem.